# Only getting "no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" on certain computers

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

The program runs on multiple computers within the same network. The mail is sent through an internal server. When I try to send an email from SmtpClient, it works on some computers but on others it gives me:

"System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.1.0.74:25"

I've tried looking it up and a lot of answers talk about the firewall or the smtp server blocking requests. The problem is it only errors on certain computers, and I'm unsure what the firewall settings are supposed to be.

The code for sending the email is as follows:

```
public void SendMessage(string subject, string messageBody, string fromAddress, string toAddress)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.1.0.74", 25);

        // Set the sender's address
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

        // Allow multiple "To" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
        if (toAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string addr in toAddress.Split(';'))
            {
                if (addr.Trim() != "")
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
            }
        }

        // Set the subject and message body text
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = messageBody;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        // Set the SMTP server to be used to send the message
        //client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        System.Net.NetworkCredential a = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");
        //client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = a;
        // Send the e-mail message
        client.Send(message);
    }
```

Edit:
Pinged the IP from the computer that's not working, got the following.
 [image]

Comment: Does that port work in telnet?

Comment: Is 10.1.0.74 routable from the computers where it is not working?

Comment: When I do telnet 10.1.0.74 25 I get "Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed." I'm not sure how to tell what you're asking Sean.

Comment: And can you ping that IP from a computer that is unable to connect?

Comment: If you cannot get a telnet connection using `telnet 10.1.0.74 25` then there is no way that you can send emails from that machine. I think you need to see if there are any differences in network configuration for the machines that can send emails and ones that can't. Perhaps they are on a different sub-domain?

Comment: It's absolutely possible they're on a different sub-domain. What do I look for in the network configuration and where do I find that?

Answer (score 4):

Enable SSL in your client and try other ports:

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Port = 587;
// or 
client.Port = 465;
```

Also you can check the connection with cmd command:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

Successful response usually looks like:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP
```